# why duplicate messages happen in multi brokers of activemq cluster?

Tags: activemq-classic

There're 2 brokers which are configured as a cluster through network connector.

Allways, messages are sent by a producer to broker0, and consumed by a consumer of broker0. But we found that some duplicated messages are sent to broker1, even broker0 are working well.
That's say, this duplicated messages are contains in both broker0 and broker1.  Could anyone tell me the reason ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of situation can occur, if you are trying to use two independent ActiveMQ instances in a cluster and client has been given access to both broker URLs.
The solution is to use the master-slave feature that is designed to provide high availability.